# VirtualBox ignores DACDev setting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, audio

I use 2 sound cards. My main sound card runs JACK and bridged PulseAudio (hw:2). The other one is free (hw:0).

Because the ALSA audio driver in VirtualBox has the lowest latency, I am using it. However sound does not work. Doing:

```
$ sudo vboxmanage setextradata "windows" "VBoxInternal/Devices/hda/0/LUN#0/Config/Audio/Alsa/DACDev" "pulse"
```

or

```
$ sudo vboxmanage setextradata "windows" "VBoxInternal/Devices/hda/0/LUN#0/Config/Audio/Alsa/DACDev" "hw:0,0"
```

does not work either.

How can I get sound to play over any of my sound cards?

- *OS:* Kubuntu 15.04
- **vboxmanage --version:** `5.0.4r102546`
- **uname -a:** `Linux linux 3.19.0-28-lowlatency #30-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 31 16:36:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. This is what I did:

1. Added myself to vboxusers group
2. Added the following to ~/.asoundrc:

   ```
   pcm.!default {
      type pulse
   }
   ```
3. Moved all VMs from root to my user and changed owner/group
4. Moved /root/.config/VirtualBox/* to ~/.config/VirtualBox/, changed owner/group and changed VM paths
5. Not using sudo anymore for vboxmanage